# C++ const method on non const pointer member

Tags: c++, object, pointers, member-functions, function-qualifier

I was wondering how protect a non const pointer member from an object throught a const method. For example:

```
class B{
    public:
        B(){
            this->val=0;
        }

        void setVal(){
            this->val = 2;
        }

    private:
        int val;
};

class A{
    public:
        A():b(new B){}
        void changeMemberFromConstMethod() const{
            this->b->setVal();
        }
    private:
        B * b; // how to protect data pointed in A::changeMemberFromConstMethod
}
```

Is it possible to "protect" A::b data pointed from his method?
After many research on web, no satisfied reponse found yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `"Doctor, it hurts when I do this" - "So don't do that".` It's not like anyone twists your arm and forces you to call `setVal` from a const method. I suppose I don't understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: It's just for example purpose. For example It's like a guarantee I want to set i.e to no modify B data pointed.

Comment: If you don't want to modify `*b`, then just don't. I still fail to grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: First thanks for your early response.The nature of my question is about semantic protection via const.  
If b is an object the compilation fails and it's normal. I would like to guarantee this behavior. Do you see? I know if I dont want to modify *b I wont. It's just for example.

Comment: I guess he wants to see error message performing the above code.

Comment: Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c77319e2b12412f1) what you're looking for? Otherwise, I'm afraid I don't understand the question. And use the contructor's member initialization list to initialize data members instead of assignment within the body.

Comment: Not exactly. I would like this behavior without declaring B const *b

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
class deep_const_ptr {
  T* p_;
public:
  deep_const_ptr(T* p) : p_(p);

  T* operator->() { return p_;}
  const T* operator->() const { return p_;}
};

class A {
  deep_const_ptr<B> b = new B;
};
```

`deep_const_ptr` behaves like a `const T* const` pointer in `A`'s const methods, and like `T*` in non-const methods. Fleshing the class out further is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It's interesting! But how the right operator is choosen ?

Comment: I see almost. How does it work more precisely (resolution). It will try the first operator and see that the return is not const and will find the other which is correct ? That's it ?

Comment: No, overload resolution doesn't (most of the time) look at the return type. But it does look at whether the method is marked `const` or not. When called on a const object, non-const method is not viable so only const one can be used. When called on a non-const object, non-const method is preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you know these deep mechanics ? ^^ Finally do you see the purpose and the semantic way of my question?

Answer (score 7):

If you change the member of `A` from

```
    B* b;
```

to

```
    B b;
```

then you will get the expected behavior.

```
class A{
    public:
        A() : b() {}

        void changeMemberFromConstMethod() const{
            this->b.setVal(); // This will produce a compiler error. 
        }
    private:
        B b;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem you have is that a `const` method makes all the member variables `const`. In this case however, it makes the pointer `const`. Specifically, it's as if all you have is `B * const b`, which means a constant pointer to a (still) mutable `B`. If you do not declare your member variable as `const B * b`, (that is, a mutable pointer to a constant `B`), then there is no way to protect from this behavior.

If all you need is a `const B`, then by all means, define `A` like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : b(new B) {}

    // This WILL give an error now.
    void changeMemberFromConstMethod() const { b->setVal(); }
private:
    const B* b;
}
```

However, if other methods of `A` mutate `B`, then all you can do is make sure that `B` does not get mutated in your `const` methods of `A`.

Comment: I'm agree with you. But if I set:
void changeMemberFromConstMethod(){b->setVal();}
This will fails in the other hand. I would like that const method say that : const B * b const; you see ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following general approach, to protect the const-ness of objects referenced via pointers, in this situation.

1. Rename B *b

   ```
   B *my_pointer_to_b;
   ```

   And change the initialization in the constructor accordingly.
2. Implement two stubs:

   ```
   B *my_b() { return b; }
   const B *my_b() const { return b; }
   ```
3. Replace all existing references to b with my_b(), in the existing code. Going forward, in any new code, always use my_b() to return the pointer to b.

Mutable methods will get a non-const pointer to B; const methods will get a const pointer to B, and the extra step of renaming makes sure that all existing code is forced to comply with the new regime.

Comment: It's an intersting approach. But it's a little twisted ^^. How is it possible that the right method is found according const or not method?

Comment: A const method can only invoke other const methods. In an const method, "this" is a constant pointer, not a mutable pointer. This is really a fairly common design pattern.