# operator shouldn't be constant but it can be

Tags: c++, class, variables, constants, operator-keyword

I implemented a class MyMatrix that holds a pointer to an abstract class Matrix (the pointer is _matrix).
the operator += calls the method add and adds the _matrix variables.
therefore, _matrix which is a class variable is changed, thus the += operator CANNOT be constant, 
but for some reason the compiler allows me to set it as const, and there are no exceptions.
why is that?

```
const MyMatrix& MyMatrix::operator +=(const MyMatrix& other) const
{
    _matrix->add(*other._matrix);
    return *this;
}
```

this is add:

```
void add(Matrix &other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.getSize(); i++)
    {
        Pair indexPair = other.getCurrentIndex();
        double value = other.getValue(indexPair);
        pair<Pair, double> pairToAdd(indexPair, value);
        other.next();
        if (pairToAdd.second != 0)
        {
            setValue(pairToAdd.first, getValue(pairToAdd.first) + pairToAdd.second);
        }
    }
    initializeIterator();
}
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code, particularly the class definition. Perhaps `add` is (mistakenly?) `const`. (Perhaps `add` returns the result of the addition and this `operator` doesn't actually change anything?)

Comment: Can you add the signature for `Matrix::add` function and the declaration for _matrix?

Comment: `_matrix->add(*other._matrix);` shouldn't even compile unless `_matrix` is `mutable` and/or `add()` is `const` also.

Comment: add() isn't const and _matrix is not mutable.

Comment: @greg Is `_matrix` a pointer? I believe it was covered in another question that the `const` qualifier on member functions makes pointer data members turn into `T* const t`, not `const T* t`.

Answer (score 6):

`operator+=` is allowed to be const because most probably you have declared the `_matrix` member as a simple pointer. Therefore, `operator+=` does not change the state of `MyMatrix` because you are not changing the pointer, but the object pointed to.

It is up to you to decide whether it is a good idea to declare `operator+=` as const. Most probably it is not even if the compiler allows it. It will only confuse the users of your class.

Answer (score 5):

The `const` method makes the:

```
Matrix* _matrix;
```

pointer *constant* in the **following** manner:

```
Matrix* const _matrix;
```

not in that way:

```
const Matrix* _matrix;
```

That is, the **pointer** is const, not the **pointee**. Hence, you can call non-const methods on `_matrix`.

If you want to force constness of a pointee in a const method, use the trick from [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576257/3953764)